# How to specify dynamic order by clause in Oracle

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, sql-order-by, oracle12c

I have an Oracle Stored Procedure which is responsible for query data paginated. It receives the text to search, the offset and the page number.
Now I want to add two new parameters to sort the query result before paginating it. My question is, how can I specify the dynamic order and direction.

For now, I now that I should use CASE clause to specify the column but I need to add if is ASC or DESC.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE search_city_paged (
        in_search_key     IN                VARCHAR2,
        in_offset         IN                NUMBER,
        in_num_elements   IN                NUMBER,
        in_polling_place  IN                VARCHAR2,
        in_order_by       IN                NUMBER,
        in_order_dir      IN                VARCHAR2,
        out_city          OUT               SYS_REFCURSOR
    ) AS

BEGIN

    OPEN out_citizens FOR 
        SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (),
               cit.city_code,
               cit.city_name,
               cit.city_zip,
               cit.city_cities
        FROM city cit
        WHERE CATSEARCH(cit.FULL_TEXT_SEARCH, l_in_search_key, NULL)>0
        ORDER BY ???
        OFFSET in_offset ROWS FETCH FIRST in_num_elements ROWS ONLY;
END search_city_paged;
```

If I receive in the new parameters 1 and ASC, the result is sorted by city_code ASC.
If I receive in the new parameters 1 and DESC, the result is sorted by city_code DESC.
If I receive in the new parameters 2 and ASC, the result is sorted by city_name ASC.
If I receive in the new parameters 2 and DESC, the result is sorted by city_name DESC.

And... in the same way on each column that I must allow sorting results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order by two outer `CASE` expressions, one `ASC` one `DESC`. In the first one check if you want to sort `ASC` and if not let the expression return a constant or `NULL`, i.e. it doesn't change the order. For the case you want to sort `ASC` add an inner `CASE` expression, that returns the column to sort by. Analogously handle the `DESC` case.

```
...
ORDER BY CASE
           WHEN in_order_dir = 'ASC' THEN
             CASE
               WHEN in_order_by = 1 THEN
                 city_code
               WHEN in_order_by = 2 THEN
                 city_name
               ...
             END
         END ASC,
         CASE
           WHEN in_order_dir = 'DESC' THEN
             CASE
               WHEN in_order_by = 1 THEN
                 city_code
               WHEN in_order_by = 2 THEN
                 city_name
               ...
             END
         END DESC;
```

Maybe you have to adapt it because of type incompatibilities between the columns, I can't tell that from what you posted. But it should convey the general concept.

---

Edit:

On the type problem:

One possibility is to convert the columns to compatible data types in a way the order is kept. For instance, if you have a `char_column` (of the type `char`), a `date_column` and an `integer_column` (of `date` and `integer`) you could do

```
to_char(date_column, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
```

to convert the date and

```
lpad(11, 38, '0')
```

to convert the integer to `char`.

The cleaner thing to do, but the one with more work to do (for the programmer, in terms of performance there should be no significant difference whatsoever) is to split the expressions once more. I.e. have an outer `CASE` for each type your columns are for each direction.

Like

```
ORDER BY CASE
           WHEN in_order_dir = 'ASC' THEN
             CASE
               WHEN in_order_by = 1 THEN
                 char_column1
               WHEN in_order_by = 2 THEN
                 char_column2
               ...
             END
         END ASC,
         CASE
           WHEN in_order_dir = 'ASC' THEN
             CASE
               WHEN in_order_by = 3 THEN
                 date_column1
               WHEN in_order_by = 4 THEN
                 date_column2
               ...
             END
         END ASC,
```

and so on for all types and analogously for `DESC`. Remember, if the column isn't meant to be sorted after such `CASE` will yield `NULL` and sorting by that won't influence the order.

Comment: A couple of additional questions, how can I add more than one column to a case? and when I use specify date type columns it throws "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got DATE", how can I specify the order by dates?

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful.